# Something like sharepoint but built in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sharepoint

Are there any gems, plugins, frameworks etc that give sharepoint like functionality (list and file management & versioning) but are based on ruby on rails?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to be able to see diffs between the files, then you'll need to use something like [GitWeb](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Gitweb) ([install](http://gofedora.com/how-to-install-configure-gitweb/))

But, if you just want simple file uploading with versioning, use [Paperclip](http://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) for file attachments and [acts_as_versioned](http://github.com/technoweenie/acts_as_versioned) to do versioning.

Comment: I guess I can do the lists and lists of lists etc with simple active record models as well. I guess I was wondering more for something put together already more than having to cobble together & build my own users/roles/permission/lists/lists of lists/attachments, versioning etc. Seems like I could build something descent in a few days, I was just looking for a jumpstart to this.